# pandas dataframe: meaning of .index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to understand the meaning of the output of the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

index = ['index1','index2','index3']
columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], index=index, columns=columns)
print df.index
```

I would expect just a list containing the index of the dataframe:

['index1, 'index2', 'index3']

however the output is:

Index([u'index1', u'index2', u'index3'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 0):

This is the pretty output of the [`pandas.Index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html#pandas.Index) object, if you look at the type it shows the class type:

```
In [45]:
index = ['index1','index2','index3']
columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], index=index, columns=columns)
df.index

Out[45]:
Index(['index1', 'index2', 'index3'], dtype='object')

In [46]:
type(df.index)

Out[46]:
pandas.indexes.base.Index
```

So what it shows is that you have an `Index` type with the elements 'index1' and so on, the dtype is `object` which is `str`

if you didn't pass your list of strings for the index you get the default int index which is the new type `RangeIndex`:

```
In [47]:
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], columns=columns)
df.index

Out[47]:
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
```

If you wanted a list of the values:

```
In [51]:    
list(df.index)

Out[51]:
['index1', 'index2', 'index3']
```

Comment: Why dtype is an 'object' and not something more specific (such as str, list, etc.)?

Comment: It's from `numpy`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html so it's essentially how the `dtype` is represented when it's not a fundamental type so not boolean, int, float, datetime, category, so str, lists, dicts, sets will all get lumped into `object`