# How to append strings to Pandas Index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [1, 2, 3]}, index=['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ'])
df
        d
FOO     1
BAR     2
BAZ     3
```

What I want to do is to append two strings in front of the index.

```
str1 = "x"
str2 = "y"
```

Yielding:

```
            d
x_y.FOO     1
x_y.BAR     2
x_y.BAZ     3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `df.index="x_y."+df.index` or `df.index=str1+'_'+str2+df.index`?

Comment: `df.index=f"{str1}_{str2}."+df.index`

Comment: @scamander hadn't [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68569678/12446721) solved your problem? You haven't responded anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [1, 2, 3]}, index=['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ'])
print(df)
"""
        d
FOO     1
BAR     2
BAZ     3
"""
str1 = "x"
str2 = "y"
df.index=f"{str1}_{str2}."+df.index
print(df)
"""
         d
x_y.FOO  1
x_y.BAR  2
x_y.BAZ  3
"""
```

We are just `adding` that `same string` in all of the `index` of `df`. You can explore for about `index` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569952/pandas-dataframe-meaning-of-index)

**Note :** This will only work if index is already `str` this wouldn't work on a `RangeIndex` without

```
df.index.astype(str)
```